# Fill HTML input type via class field in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my project I have a `HTML form` that is included in my `Php` file.
The HTML file has some `JavaScript` methods to fill automatically, anyways.
In first step The `Php` connect to a remote device via `SSH` and run some commands.
The `Php` has a `class` and some `functions`,
In my next step I should read the data that had inserted in the remote device via `SSH` and fill out in `HTML` form.
I can read the data, and can display it via `echo`. ( as you will see here )
But how can I display that value into my `HTML` input type value?
Here is my HTML code :  ( I write it briefly, cause it is too long and no need to write all)

```
     <div id="linkname" >
                <label>Wireless Link Name</label>   

                <input type="text" name="ssid" id="ssid"><br>  
    </div>
```

Here is my `Php` File class and methods :

```
         <?php

        class SSHCommand{

            public $ssh;

            include('./view/config.html');   
            include('Net/SSH2.php');    


        class SSHCommand{

        public function display(){

        session_start();

        $username=$_SESSION['username'];
        $password=$_SESSION['password'];
        $ip=$_SESSION['ip'];
        $this->ssh=new Net_SSH2($ip);

       if($this->ssh->login($username, $password)) { 
          $my_array= explode("\n", $this->ssh->exec('some command'));
          foreach($my_array as $cat) {  
         if(strpos($cat, "name=") !== false) { 
         // I should here insert the $cat value into  ssid input
        break;
    } else { 
        // Do nothing
    }
}   
        } else echo 'wrong';
    }
    }
        $sshCommand=new SSHCommand(); 
        $sshCommand->display();
    ?>
```

As you see I fill an `array`, I search for a specific text in the array, like

```
name=
```

, and want insert that value into the input type `ssid`.

How can I do that in Php code?
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing that, considering how you are importing the html file, is to call a javascript script to pass a value to the input.

```
if(strpos($cat, "name=") !== false) { 
  echo '<script>document.querySelector("#ssid").value = "' . $cat . '";</script>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir, and could you take a look at this question? 
Thanks : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44243515/html-form-display-the-first-options-and-empty-inputs-after-submit